# Infinite redirection using middleware

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to implement simple middleware logic and got

> Detected an infinite redirection in a navigation guard when going from
> "/" to "/login". Aborting to avoid a Stack Overflow. This will break
> in production if not fixed.

I know that somewhere in my code it redirects more than once, but cannot find where.

Here is the **router**:

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from 'vue-router'
import store from '@/store'

/* Guest Component */
const Login = () => import('@/components/Login.vue')
const Register = () => import('@/components/Register.vue')
/* Guest Component */

/* Layouts */
const DahboardLayout = () => import('@/components/layouts/Default.vue')
/* Layouts */

/* Authenticated Component */
const Dashboard = () => import('@/components/Dashboard.vue')
/* Authenticated Component */


const routes = [
    {
        name: "login",
        path: "/login",
        component: Login,
        meta: {
            middleware: "guest",
            title: `Login`
        }
    },
    {
        name: "register",
        path: "/register",
        component: Register,
        meta: {
            middleware: "guest",
            title: `Register`
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/",
        component: DahboardLayout,
        meta: {
            middleware: ["all"]
        },
        children: [
            {
                name: "dashboard",
                path: '/',
                component: Dashboard,
                meta: {
                    title: `Dashboard`
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes, // short for `routes: routes`
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    document.title = to.meta.title
    if (to.meta.middleware == "all") {
        return next();
    } else if (to.meta.middleware == "guest") {
        if (store.state.auth.authenticated) {
            return next({ name: "login" })
        } else {
            return next()
        }
    } else if (to.meta.middleware == "auth") {
        if (store.state.auth.authenticated) {
            return next()
        } else {
            return next({ name: "login" })
        }
    }
})

export default router
```

And in **Default.vue** component:

```
<router-link :to="{name:'login'}">Login</router-link>
```

Comment: Tangential: (a) where does the `auth` meta.middleware come in to play? (b) For `guest` if it's authenticated do you really want to go to `login`?

Comment: @DaveNewton If guest is autneticated he isn't guest anymore.

Comment: Right, so why go to `login` if they're authenticated? Is `...authenticated` unrelated to whether or not they've logged in?

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for you help, I think that I handle it, could you check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @DaveNewton questions I changed it like that and it works fine:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    document.title = to.meta.title
    if (to.meta.middleware == "all") {
        return next();
    } else if (to.meta.middleware == "guest") {
        if (!store.state.auth.authenticated) {
            return next()
        }
    } else if (to.meta.middleware == "auth") {
        if (store.state.auth.authenticated) {
            return next()
        } else {
            return next({ name: "login" })
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you redirect in the `beforeEach` navigation guard the new route will also have to go through the navigation guard.  The infinite loop is from trying to redirect to the login route, and always hitting this code:

```js
else if (to.meta.middleware == "guest") {
        if (store.state.auth.authenticated) {
            return next({ name: "login" })
```

So you redirect to login, which redirects to login, which redirects... etc. You need to add some other condition to just `return next()` when going to the login route in this situation, maybe like this:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  document.title = to.meta.title;
  if (to.meta.middleware == 'all' || to.name === 'login') {
    return next();
  }
  ...
```

Comment: In this case when user is already autneticated he will be able to access /login again